# Can letter-spacing be applied to UINavigationBar's title with Pixate?

Tags: css, uinavigationbar, letter-spacing, pixate

The letter-spacing property appears to have no effect on the title child in a navigation bar using Pixate.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS the UINavigationBar title's attributed text only supports font, text color, text shadow color, and text shadow offset. To get letter-spacing you need to create your own text field, assign the NSKernAttributeName attribute to it, and then assign it to the titleView of your NavigationItem. This is done per nav page, not generically for the UINavigationBar.